# angular directive elementRef - querying next element that match class

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have a html structure like

```
<div class="1"><input directive></div>
<div class="2"></div>
<div class="1"><input></div>
<div class="2"></div>
```

I want to use a directive to do something like focus() on the next element of the same class. Using a simple nextElementSibling won't work.
But The order of parent elements is regular, in this case alternating.

I can achieve it by using

```
this.elElRef.nativeElement.parentElement.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild
```

but that is neither really reliable nor elegant. Is there a way I could like query the next search result for that element, e.g input?

Thanks!

Comment: probably not, but why not put a directive on that element you want to focus?

Comment: i want to autofocus to the next input which could be nested somewhere

Comment: You should probably find a more general way to achieve this, but without more code it's hard to determine. For instance, what's creating the html structure? Is it an `*ngFor` or is it all hardcoded?

Comment: thanks for your inputs, i'm just generally interessted, if there was any way to query like you have a querySelector for @ViewChild

Answer (score 1):

Doing this with a directive isn't very pretty due to finding the other inputs arbitrarily.
I suggest a using a combination of `#localVar` and `localVar.focus()`
Here's an example of how you might implement it.

```
<div class="1"><input (keydown.enter)="input2.focus()"></div>
<div class="2"></div>
<div class="1"><input #input2 (keydown.enter)="input3.focus()"></div>
```

Here's a stackbliz (similar to plunkr) example of it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vdg9a7g4f

Comment: thanks for the reply, this was the alternative i'm trying to avoid. But is there isn't any querying method i guess this is the best anwser.

Comment: @Toxicable, will this trick work in dynamically created elements(inside `*ngFor`)? When I press enter on an input field then I want to add a new row to the array and this input fields will come inside an `*ngFor` so how should I give a unique template variable to dynamically created input elements?